# Use ActionCable from remote origin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I try to use ActionCable to create a websocket between my Rails application and a traditional html page.

I can only use "Subscribe" in my js script, if I try the speak command I got an error :
`"Received unrecognized command in {"command"=>"speak", "identifier"=>"{\"channel\":\"StreamChannel\",\"content\":\"Hi everyone !\"}"}"`.

My code : (https://gist.github.com/fclement21/ebd3be213f1fa5746321bd75284601b0)

JS

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3000/cable"); 
  var id = { channel: 'StreamChannel'};
  var sub_cmd = {
    command: 'subscribe',
    identifier: JSON.stringify(id)
  }

  ws.onclose = function() { // thing to do on close
  };
  ws.onerror = function() { // thing to do on error
  };
  ws.onmessage = function(e) { // thing to do on message
    data = JSON.parse(e.data);
    console.log(data);
    if(data.message.status == "200"){
      var id_test = { channel: 'StreamChannel', content: "Hi everyone !"};
      var stream_id = {
        command: 'speak',
        identifier: JSON.stringify(id_test)
      }
      ws.send(JSON.stringify(stream_id));
    }
  };
  ws.onopen = function(e) { 
    ws.send(JSON.stringify(sub_cmd));
  };
```

My Stream_channel.rb

```
class StreamChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "stream_test"
    ActionCable.server.broadcast "stream_test", message: "You are now connected !", status: 200
  end
  def speak
    ActionCable.server.broadcast "stream_test", message: "Your message has been sended", status: 200
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to figure it out thanks to the readme [on this GitHub repo](https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/action_cable_client). It seems that ActionCable uses the "message" command for actually sending things. The key thing to add is that you also need an "action" attribute in the provided JSON. Using your posted code as an example:

```
if(data.message.status == "200"){
  var id_test = { channel: 'StreamChannel' };
  var stream_id = {
    command: 'message',
    identifier: JSON.stringify(id_test),
    data: JSON.stringify({action: "speak", content: "Hi everyone !"})
  }
  ws.send(JSON.stringify(stream_id));
}
```